# contains function for int in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

what is the best way to figure out what number the integer contains
for example:
i have a int that is `96` and i want to see if it has `9` return something and if it has not return something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// this will return true if your int contains the pattern
bool intContains(myInt,pattern){
   return myInt.toString().contains(pattern.toString());
}
```